# Extjs with CodeIgniter: Can't delete a user from a grid

Tags: php, codeigniter, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am following the following tutorial:

http://mrhawley.com/

Problem is it doesn't finish. However, up to the point it goes it is the best tutorial around for developing an extjs app with sencha cmd and using CodeIgniter as a backend framework.

I decided to try to fill in the gaps and guess at where he was going. I got the create /read and update methods all working nicely but I can't seem to get delete to work.

Here is my extjs store:

```
Ext.define('BugTracker.store.user.UserList', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: [
    'BugTracker.model.user.UserList'
],
constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            model: 'BugTracker.model.user.UserList',
            autoLoad: false,
            remoteFilter: false,
            remoteSort: false,
            pageSize: 5,
            sorters: {
                property: 'username',
                direction: 'asc'
            },
            proxy: {
                type: 'rest',
                actionMethods: {
                    create: 'POST',
                    read: 'GET',
                    update: 'POST',
                    destroy: 'POST'
                },
                api: {
                    create: 'index.php/user/new_user',
                    read: 'index.php/user/get_users',
                    update: 'index.php/user/update_user',
                    destroy: 'index.php/user/delete_user'
                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data'
                },
                writer: {
                    type: 'json',
                    writeAllFields: false,
                    allowSingle: false,
                    encode: true,
                    root: 'data'
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
}
});
```

and here is my extjs controller:

```
Ext.define('BugTracker.controller.user.UserAdmin', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
refs: [
    {
        ref:'userForm',
        selector:'userform'
    }
],
init: function(){
    this.control({
        'maintoolbar button[action=openUserAdminPanel]':{
            click:function(){
                var panel =  Ext.widget('useradminpanel');
                panel.show();
            }
        },
        'userform button[action=saveUser]':{
            click:function(button){
                var form = button.up('form').getForm(),
                    values = form.getValues(),
                    store = Ext.getStore('user.UserList');

                if (form.isValid()) {
                    switch (button.getText()){
                        case 'Save':
                            store.create(values);
                            break;
                        case 'Update':
                            var record = form.getRecord();
                            record.set(values);
                            store.update();
                            button.setText('Save');
                    }
                    this.LoadUserList();
                    this.ResetForm(form);
                }
            }
        },
        'userform button[action=deleteUser]':{
            click:function(button){
                var form = button.up('form').getForm(),
                    values = form.getValues(),
                    store = Ext.getStore('user.UserList');
                if (form.isValid()) {
                    Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Delete',
                        'Are you sure you want to delete user "' + values.username + '"?',
                        function(button){
                            switch (button) {
                                case 'yes':
                                    store.destroy(values.id);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        });
                    this.LoadUserList();
                }
                this.ResetForm(form);
            }
        },
        'userlist':{
            afterrender:this.LoadUserList,

            cellclick:function(grid,td,cellIndex,record,tr,rowIndex,e,eOpts){
                var form = this.getUserForm(),
                    button = form.down('button[action=saveUser]');
                form.loadRecord(record);
                button.setText('Update');
            }
        }
    });
},
ResetForm:function(form){
    form._record = null;
    form.reset();
},
LoadUserList:function(){
    var store = Ext.getStore('user.UserList');
    store.removeAll();
    store.load();
}
});
```

As you can see when I click on the delete button it calls store.destroy and that sends a POST call to index.php/users/delete_user. However, it is sending an empty array. I have dumped out values.id and it comes up with the right ID. I have tried sending the entire array. No matter what I do it sends an empty array.

Comment: Is more code needed? Do i need more specifics? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you verify it is sending an empty array over the network via inspector or somesuch? Or are you just seeing an empty array on the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was dumping out the 'data' key on the backend to determine what was being sent. This was coming up with an empty array. However, I noticed that when I called `store.destroy(values)` that 'id' was sent but it was not part of the data key. I then proceeded to account for this and the deletion works fine.

The reason I was confused is because i set the reader and the writer of the proxy to have a root of "data". However, I guess that deleting items does not fall under either of these and therefore does not put its id inside of the 'data' root. Thank you @stormdrain for giving me a hint towards the issue!